# Xcode 6 ScrollView with Universal Layout

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout, xcode6

With Xcode 6, w:Any and H:Any, i want to make a view that can be scrolled horizontally, there is 4 view in the scrollview placed horizontally, and one is take full width, (see picture)

How to achieve this with Xcode 6 new universal layout paradigm?

i mean, i am confused with what constraints i should use for each element to make it work

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in Xcode 5 you need to make the contents of the scroll view a multiple of the outside of the scroll view, and both the scroll view and content view need there bounds to be fully constrained.

To do this for different width screens:

- Make the scroll view and constrain its bounds.
- Add a UIView into the scroll view to constrain the contents size of the Scroll view, we'll call it a content view.
- Add constraints to the outside of the content view so that the contents of the scroll view is bounded by it.
- Make the content view equal widths to the scroll view.
- Edit the equal widths constraint so the content views width is a multiple of the scroll views widths (the multiple needs to be the number of pages)
- Add relevant height constraint to the content view (probably equal height with the scroll view).

[Here's](http://hg.twistedape.me.uk/pagingscrollview) a sample project that does this. For a more detailed explanation there is a blog post [here](http://www.twistedape.me.uk/blog/blog/2014/09/08/horizontal-paging-scroll-view-with-varying-width-in-storyboards/)

Comment: Thank you, but as you said, i have no problem with XCode 5, that is why i purpossedly put XCode 6 in my question title, anyway i will try your suggestion

Comment: The sample project (and blog) was written entirely using Xcode 6 and works on different width screens so hopefully that should help. The point of the Xcode 5 comment is the concept of constraining both the outside and inside hasn't changed.

Comment: wow, i try it step by step without missing any step, and it works... thanks James, i accept your answer